# why are :before and :after not showing?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```css
main {
  width         : 100%;
  position      : relative;
  border-radius : 1.5rem;
  padding       : 0.125rem 1.5rem 1.5 rem 1.5rem margin-top: 3rem
  }
main:before {
  content          : "";
  width            : calc(96.5% - 1.5rem);
  z-index          : -1;
  margin-top       : -0.87rem;
  border-radius    : 1.6rem;
  position         : absolute;
  left             : 0px;
  right            : 0rem;
  top              : 0rem;
  margin-left      : auto;
  margin-right     : auto;
  height           : 5rem;
  background-color : rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.2);
  }
main:after {
  content          : "";
  width            : calc(92.5% - 1.5rem);
  z-index          : -2;
  margin-top       : -1.76rem;
  border-radius    : 1.6rem;
  position         : absolute;
  left             : 0px;
  right            : 0rem;
  top              : 0rem;
  margin-left      : auto;
  margin-right     : auto;
  height           : 5rem;
  background-color : #dbdbdb1e;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg-gray-50 h-screen col-span-8">
  <div class="pb-6 pr-6 h-screen overflow-y-auto -mb-20 relative">
    <main class="bg-gray-100 w-full rounded-3xl pt-0.5 pb-6 px-6 mt-12 relative" style="min-height: calc(100% - 4.5rem)">
      content
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Considering the above HTML and CSS, I should see two different boxes behind the maincontent. But it's not showing a thing. In the inspector I can find the :before and :after, it's got the right width / position / etc but it is just not showing. What am I missing?

note: I just added the main css in this code block for people who aren't familiar with Tailwind. In the actual code there is no CSS in the style tag, just Tailwindclasses (except for the :before and :after)

Comment: The boxes are there, just a bit hard to see on a white background. Also you're missing a semicolon after ```padding: 0.125rem 1.5rem 1.5 rem 1.5rem```

Comment: I've used your exact code to create a codepen, and then changed the background colors. I can see something: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/YzvPXyG

Comment: why didn't see that before with your browser's inspector ?

Comment: I am curious, how did you include the CSS in your HTML file?

Comment: @VilleKoo When I change the colors, I don't see anything. The semicolon is not needed there, as I'm using TailwindCSS

Comment: @MisterJojo, what do you mean?

Comment: @KikoSoftware TailwindCSS

Comment: If your solution is TailwindCSS then the cause can probably be found there.

Comment: On you browser use `F12` key....

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? Please don't answer with just "Yes" or "No".